# getting difficulty in starting my miniproject packet tracer in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, changelistener

i am a beginner in java and i am  trying to create packet tracer in java and now i am starting GUI with eclipse. i am trying to change my button name start to restart and resume to pause in action listener i don't know how to change the name of the button can anyone help me?
my code is

```
Jbutton btnResume = new Jbutton("Resume");
brnResume.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0){
JButton btnResume = new Jbutton("Pause");
}}
```

it's not working help me with this method

Comment: The B in the `JButton` should be capitalised.  You will get a syntax error otherwise.

Comment: For better more complete help, consider creating and posting a valid [mcve].

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to create a new variable with the same name with the assumption that this will change the object that the original variable refers to. This means that you are confused about what objects are, and how reference variables work. Understand that the original btnResume variable refers to a JButton object, and this object is likely displayed in the GUI. Within a ChangeListener (that we're not sure how it gets called or even if it gets called), you are creating a new JButton object, and assigning it to a new local variable. Note that this new JButton is not the same as the one currently displayed, and so setting the new button's text will have no effect on the displayed JButton.

Instead you'll likely want to use the original variable, which hopefully is within the scope of the ChangeListener code, and hopefully still refers to the same JButton object, and call `setText(...)` on the original object. Something like:

```
Jbutton btnResume = new JButton("Resume");

brnResume.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0){
        // JButton btnResume = new Jbutton("Pause");
        btnResume.setText("Pause");
    }
}
```

Myself, I'd consider doing things differently: swapping the JButton's Action with a new Action, one that not only shows the "Pause" text, but also holds the pause behaviors.

Note that for better more complete help, consider creating and posting a valid [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) program with your question.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SwapActions extends JPanel {
    private Action resumeAction = new ResumeAction("Resume", KeyEvent.VK_R);
    private Action pauseAction = new PauseAction("Pause", KeyEvent.VK_P);
    private JButton resumePauseBtn = new JButton(resumeAction);

    public SwapActions() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

        add(resumePauseBtn);
    }

    private class ResumeAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ResumeAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO resume code here

            // **** swap Actions here! ****
            ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setAction(pauseAction);
        }
    }

    private class PauseAction extends AbstractAction {
        public PauseAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO pause code here

            // **** swap Actions here! ****
            ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setAction(resumeAction);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SwapActions mainPanel = new SwapActions();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swap Actions");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

In the AbstractActions, I swap the action of the source (here the JButton) with this line:

```
((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setAction(resumeAction);
```

---

Regarding:

> i tried the 1st one and it is showing that change the button to final after changed that button then when i placed the cursor on the button it's changing the name .i want it changed when i clicked it why it is not doing that

You've got the change code within a ChangeListener, and this listener does not respond to button presses. Instead, if you want to respond to button presses, use ActionListeners with `addActionListener(...)` or AbstractAction with `setAction(...)` (as I show above).

Most important, please read the Swing tutorials as you seem to be doing a lot of guessing, and that only leads to frustration. The tutorials are very comprehensive and helpful with decent code examples. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Comment: thanks bro for quick response i tried the 1st one and it is showing that change the button to final after changed that button then when i placed the cursor on the button it's changing the name .i want it changed when i clicked it why it is not doing that

Comment: @RamaKrishnaPolumuru: please see edits to answer, added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: ok i will see it thank you once again for helping me